# What is an elastic network interface (ENI) and when would you use it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

An elastic network interface is defined as a virtual network interface https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html.

I was wondering what use cases exist of this. Why would not I simply put directly an instance instead of having to use the eni, and attach it to an instance.

Thks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decoupling the **ENI** from the **EC2** instance allows you far more flexibility.

You can connect several **ENIs** to the same **EC2** instance and be attached to different subnets, for example:

- *ENI A connected to a public-facing subnet*
- *ENI B connected to an internal private subnet*

You could, for example, attach an **ENI** to a running **EC2** instance, or you could have it live after the EC2 instance is deleted.

As a form of "cheap" high availability: Attach a **ENI** to an **EC2** instance; if the instance dies launch another one and attach the **ENI** to it. Traffic flow will only be interrupted for a short period.

There are many scenarios where this flexibility comes in handy.